# how to make a tableview to expand and collapse like as outlineview?

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard

is it possible to expand and collapse a NStableview like as NSoutlineview?  i'm using osx 10.6 and also want to animate the tableview while expanded and collapsed.

Comment: If you want your NSTableView to behave like an NSOutlineView, why don't you use NSOutlineView in the first place?

Comment: just i want to know is it possible?